# python3 / pymongo "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" within class

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Having some fun with some with python, new and keen but feeling defeated. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Am I trying to query mongo from within a flask app, I appear to be missing something or performing an illegal action with:

```
local_settings = Database.find_sort(AdminConstants.COLLECTION, "admin.created_date", -1, 1)
```

This sits beneath the class and appears to return None. This shouldn't be the case as running the commands (without the class) return a value on the command line. I'll add this at the end in hope someone can clear this up for me. Moving this outside the class still causes the error - very frustrating to see it work on the terminal and fail where I need it.

Edit: The database is of course initialized at this point of the program.
Edit2: Never be too sure of yourself ;)

Code:
database.py

```
import pymongo
class Database(object):
    URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.URI)
        Database.DATABASE = client['cvm']

    @staticmethod
    def find_sort(collection, query, direction, limit):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find({}).sort(query, direction).limit(limit)
```

admin.py

```
from src.common.database import Database

class Admin(object):
    local_settings = Database.find_sort(AdminConstants.COLLECTION, "admin.created_date", -1, 1)
```

error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.app import app
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/app.py", line 19, in <module>
    from src.models.admin.views import admin_blueprint
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/models/admin/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.models.admin.admin import Admin
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/models/admin/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Admin(object):
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/models/admin/admin.py", line 8, in Admin
    local_settings = Database.find_sort(AdminConstants.COLLECTION, "admin.created_date", -1, 1)
  File "/home/frank/PycharmProjects/cvm/src/common/database.py", line 27, in find_sort
    return (Database.DATABASE[collection].find({}).sort(query, direction).limit(limit))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

terminal:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug  9 2016, 15:36:17)
>>> import pymongo
>>> URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(URI)
>>> DATABASE = client['cvm']
>>> def find_sort(collection, query, direction, limit):
...     return DATABASE[collection].find().sort(query, direction).limit(limit)
... 
>>> COLLECTION = "admin"
>>> tmp1 = find_sort(COLLECTION, "created_date", -1, 1)
>>> list(tmp1)
[{'created_date': '20161212', '_id': ObjectId('5863f28d101bbd88b70be948')}]
```

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Well you say the database is initialised, but that error clearly tells you it isn't - and I don't know how it could be. Where do you think you're doing that?

Comment: I thought I was initialising in my app.py, this was not the case and needed to call for the initialisation in the admin class. I didn't think this was required but clearly an oversight by a novice. Please post as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As spotted by Daniel Roseman the databse was not initialised. I believed this to be carried through from an earlier call, but was required within the class.

```
Well you say the database is initialised, but that error clearly tells you it isn't - and I don't know how it could be. Where do you think you're doing that? – Daniel Roseman Dec 29 '16 at 17:53


I thought I was initialising in my app.py, this was not the case and needed to call for the initialisation in the admin class. I didn't think this was required but clearly an oversight by a novice. Please post as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you – the_frank Dec 30 '16 at 11:41
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your `Database` class to call the `find_sort` on. You can then use the python `self`  [keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

```
class Database(object):
    URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    DATABASE = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize(self):
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.URI)
        self.DATABASE = client['cvm']

    @staticmethod
    def find_sort(self, collection, query, direction, limit):
        return self.DATABASE[collection].find({}).sort(query, direction).limit(limit)
```

then this should work:

```
Database().find_sort(AdminConstants.COLLECTION, "admin.created_date", -1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was was actually an oversight on my behalf, I believed my app.py would be initialising the database for the whole app, whereas I am required to initialise as and when a class needs it.